# Failed to add bg image in css file

Tags: php, html, css

Simply, I am trying to add background image in css code.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-image:url(../img/bg1.jpg);
}
```

But background image does not appear while testing with localhost/foldername/index.php

It is interesting that, I can edit background color, (  `background-color:#993`).

My folder tree is like this;

```
+Main Folder
  +css
     style.css
  +img
     bg1.jpg
```

Could you help me why I cannot add background image into css body.

Comment: your image name file is different...so it should be like this ->  background: url(../Img/backgroundimage.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;

Comment: folder tree was just example.. So it is not different

Comment: beware of the case sensitivity

Comment: @LuisP.A. there is no problem about image name, or case sensitivity, I also used dreamweaver and take image with browse tool. but it is same.

Comment: Try to call it like this background-image:url(img/bg1.jpg);

Comment: Open the developer tools (f12) to check if the browser has found the pic, so we can exclude a wrong path as the problem.

Comment: @SCHTAILian it cannot it is also empty

Comment: display block on the element put some hight,width to the element and/or the picture

Comment: So either the path is wrong or you have a wrong syntax, maybe as @Stewartside wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you are missing `''` round the url.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-image: url('../img/bg1.jpg');
}
```

Also, could be down to missing the repeat.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-image: url('../img/bg1.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: I also check this, but it didnt work :(.. I am using Linux pc, but I dont think that it is OS related problem.

Comment: Yes.... it is somehow my linux previligies , thank you very much to figure out this..

Comment: You don't have permission to access /mGezer/img/bg1.jpg on this server.

Comment: Yes, exactly.. I made CHOWN but forget CHMOD.. so my user cannot execute this image.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your css file is not loaded because you use a relative path. In your `link` tag make sure you add the absolute css path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: No, in my source code I have exactly same phrase, like ; <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

Comment: it is a relative path.. put a slash before css. Is not exactly the same phrase.. you are missing the slash before css

Answer (score -1):

You can just use

```
background: url(' Your Path ')
```

Instead of

```
background-image: url(' Path ')
```

Comment: that not property problem , it's about image route.